# Implementing the observer pattern with Java and MouseListener

Tags: java, oop, mouselistener

I have three classes, Main, DrawingPanel, and ToolboxPanel. ToolboxPanel contains all my buttons, including an Undo button. DrawingPanel is where I draw objects. I want the undo button to become enabled when an object is drawn on the screen, and disabled when there are no more objects left on the screen. Main creates an instance of DrawingPanel and of ToolboxPanel. I can get my undo button to work correctly if I use static methods and call, say, Main.setUndoStatus(false); from drawingPanel. The setUndoStatus then calls a setter in toolboxPanel. However, I've been reading about the Observer pattern and listeners and think I'm probably not doing it in a best-practice way.

How should I go about this using the observer pattern and/or mouse listeners correctly? (Or any "better" way of doing it).

Here's some code somewhat similar to what I'm doing.

```
public class Main
{
    DrawingPanel drawingPanel;
    ToolboxPanel toolboxPanel;

    public Main()
    {
        drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel();
        toolboxPanel = new ToolboxPanel(drawingPanel);
    }
}

//A static method here to setUndoStatus, but I feel like I shouldn't have it
public static void setUndoStatus(boolean b)
{
    {
    toolboxPanel.setUndoStatus(b);
    }
}


public class ToolboxPanel
{
    JButton undoButton;
    public ToolboxPanel(DrawingPanel drawingPanel)
    {
        undoButton = new JButton("Undo");
        undoButton.setEnabled(false);
        undoButton.addActionListener
        (
            new ActionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    drawingPanel.undo();
                    undoButton.setEnabled(drawingPanel.getUndoStatus());
                }
            }
        );
    }

    public void setUndoStatus(boolean status)
    {
        undoButton.setEnabled(status);
    }
}

public class DrawingPanel
{
    public DrawingPanel()
    {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
        {

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
            {
                //Some code here that's unrelated
                if(objectsExist == true) //If something gets drawn, whatever
                {
                    Main.setUndoStatus(true); //Don't like this
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Myself, I would **start** with my *model* class, a class completely divorced from the GUI and the event listeners, and not my control or view classes. I wonder if you're getting the cart before the horse by not considering the model now. What data should it hold? What behaviors do you need it to have? What type of listener(s) should it have? I'm not a professional, but I often give mine a SwingPropertyChangeListener with several String propertyName constants defined as either enums or constants in my model's interface.

Comment: Java has a built-in Observer/Observable pattern. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html It doesn't work for all scenarios, but should give you an idea. Also take Hovercraft's suggestion to heart. You might want to look into an MVC-like pattern.

Comment: And you are right, Birdie, avoid using static fields and methods to hold object state and behavior code. That way leads to untestable, unenhanceable code.

Comment: Will it matter that my drawingPanel is essentially both a view and a controller at the moment, as you draw on it (controller) and also can see the previously drawn objects (view)?

I guess I would use Main as my model. I'll have a look and see if I can work that out.

Comment: What matters most to me is to separate the logical parts of the program out from all the other parts, to get them far removed from user interaction, from event code, to make it as UI agnostic as humanly possible, and to make it clean and logical, to give it beauty.